# Why are my FB API posts not reaching an audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I created an app that uses the FB API to post to a page. However, posts that are published are later not shown to an audience and not seen by fans.

In this screenshot you see posts that reached an audience and posts that did not reach an audience. The ones that reached an audience were posted manually by me. The posts the reached 0 people were posted by my API application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: Apps that are not sent to review will not have visible posts.

The solution is to go to the "App Review" menu and submit the app for review

Comment: The app only needs to be set live (as opposed to development mode), for other people that don’t have a role in it to be able to see the content created via this app. Yes, that setting is now on the App Review tab – but you don’t need to actually submit for review.

Comment: You do need to submit when using extended permissions.

Comment: Not for the content created via the app to be visible to everyone, but only if you want the app to be _used_ by the general public, i.e. have _them_ login and grant permissions to it too. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921